# Set any field once for all the tests in Fitnesse table

Tags: java, fitnesse

I want to set one field in the fitnesse table, only once for all the tests. For example I want to set Operator as + for all the tests in the table.

Below is the regular table.

```
!|CalculatorFixture                |
 |Value1|Operator|Value2|calculate?|
 |3.0   |+       |5.0   |8.0       |
 |2.0   |*       |3.5   |7.0       |
```

I want something like:

```
!| CalculatorFixture      |
 |Operator                |
 |+                       |
 |Value1|Value2|calculate?|
 |3.0   |5.0   |8.0       |
 |6.0   |3.0   |9.0       |
 |5.0   |2.0   |7.0       |
```

Any Idea how can I achieve this in the fixture or in the fitnesse table?
FYI, I am using Slim: !define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}

Comment: Or can I set the field in a different table but for all the tests though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a Java static field in a previous table fixture and then access it in the CalculatorFixture.

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass 'constructor parameters' to scenarios by using `having` or `given` as first cell after the scenario name (from [FitNesse's tests](https://github.com/unclebob/fitnesse/blob/master/FitNesseRoot/FitNesse/SuiteAcceptanceTests/SuiteSlimTests/ScenarioTestSuite/UsingConstructorArgumentsFromDecisionTablesInScenarios/content.txt#L14))

```
|scenario | myDivision _ _ _|numerator, denominator, quotient|
|setNumerator    | @numerator  |
|setDenominator  | @denominator|
|check | quotient| @quotient   |

| myDivision | having |numerator| 12| 
| denominator|quotient|
|  3         |4.0     |
|  6         |2.0     |
|  4         |3.0     |
```